# How well is computer hardware protected from sudden power loss?

Tags: hardware-failure, power

I always wondered how well the computer components can handle sudden power outages due to janitor accidentally pulling the power cord, whole city block power outage or power generator failure.

Are components tested specifically for safe shutdown during production because of how common these issues are, or does it all just happen not to break most of the time because of how electric devices are generally designed to be?

Comment: Yes. No. Sometimes. It depends.

Comment: @EBGreen that is exactly not the kind of answer I am looking for.

Comment: That is because the question is too broad. Some manufacturers do test components up to a point. Some don't.

Comment: Basically there is no one good comprehensive answer to the question. That is why I made that a comment not an actual answer.

Comment: Loss of power is rarely harmful to electronic/electrical components.  However electromechanical devices such as HDDs are another story, as well as data integrity and preservation of data, although your question is only about *hardware* and not data.

Answer (score 1):

After my experience, todays computers can handle this pretty well.
Here at my company I work as a system administrator, and every weekend people (the workers) turn off the computers they work on by powering them down from the power switch instead of shutting them down properly.
There are around 60-80 computers. Every Monday around 1 PC got a boot error when starting them. (this happened mostly with older PCs: i3 and core duo) Most of the times this could be solved by powering the PC completely off and on again. Sometimes we had to replace the HDD or reinstall the operating system in them.

Recently we changed most of the computers to newer ones (i5 - i7). Since than for at least 2-3 months I personally did not experience any boot errors or computers fail because of this problem.

So my answer is: in my opinion this can affect only the HDD, it will not cause other problems. But on newer and newer devices this happens less likely.

Comment: Shutting down for the weekend is less likely to have unfinished activity than sudden power loss during the workday.  However, it's true that the main risk is data corruption on the hard disk.

Comment: There are always activities going on even when the computer is idle. Programs nowadays are well written and have protection against power loss or sudden crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the power goes out. Does it flucutuate on and off, does it burst and then go off, etc. A sudden outage like you describe would likely be the least volatile form of an unexpected shut down, but is still dangerous. Data can be corrupted on hard drives as they don't have time to complete writing/spinning.

The only time I've seen components actually burnt in for a unexpected shut down is in military applications, and we had UPS's connected on a rack next to them.